# Django REST Framework Routing

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Hello having problems figuring out what the best approach would be to create a set of routes like these below preferrably for Django-rest-framework. Routes are pseudocode and subject to change. Currently using Django 1.11

```
GET /api/<model>/<id>
GET /api/<model>/?select=<feld1>,<feld2>,<feld3>,...
GET /api/<model>/?top=20&skip=60
GET /api/<model>/<id>/<model2> # Where Model2 is also a parameter which can change
GET /api/<model>/?expand=<model2>,<model3>,...
GET /api/<model>/?filter=<filter-string>
GET /api/<model>/?search=<solr-query>
```

It should ALSO be possible to combine these except the search query

Answer (score 1):

First of all, all that following after `?` is a QueryString, no need to make URL for it.
Next, it is best practice, to create route `api/` in base `urls.py` file
And `urls.py` in another app, will be 2 urls, like this

```
url(r'^model/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$', view.id_view, name='id'),
url(r'^model/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/(P<model>[\w]+)$', view.id_model_view, name='model')
```

Comment: hmm yeah. that will do. But i was thinking of using a more elegant Solution (Router). But then again i could just copy paste these urls for each model.

Answer (score 1):

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        # filter
        'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
        # order
        'rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter',
        # search
        'rest_framework.filters.SearchFilter'
    ),
    ...
    'ORDERING_PARAM': 'ordering',
    'SEARCH_PARAM': 'search',
}
```

views.py

```
class MessageTemplateViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MessageTemplate.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MessageTemplateListSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsPublisherOrReadOnly,)
    filter_class = MessageTemplateFilter
    ordering_fields = '__all__'
    search_fields = ('subject', 'content')
```

filters.py

```
class MessageTemplateFilter(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = MessageTemplate
        fields = {
            'publisher': ['exact'],
            'subject': ['exact', 'icontains'],
            'content': ['exact', 'icontains'],
            'is_private': ['exact'],
        }
```

filter is support by [django-filter](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter),with this you can achieve

```
GET /api/<model>/<id>
GET /api/<model>/?top=20&skip=60
GET /api/<model>/?filter=<filter-string>
GET /api/<model>/?search=<solr-query>
```

for

```
GET /api/<model>/<id>/<model2>
```

you can achieve by [drf-nested-routers](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers)

for

```
GET /api/<model>/?select=<feld1>,<feld2>,<feld3>,...
```

you can modify by this serializer:

```
class DynamicFieldsModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    """
    A ModelSerializer that takes an additional `fields` argument that
    controls which fields should be displayed.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Don't pass the 'fields' arg up to the superclass
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)
        exclude = kwargs.pop('exclude', None)

        # Instantiate the superclass normally
        super(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if fields is not None:
            # Drop any fields that are not specified in the `fields` argument.
            allowed = set(fields)
            existing = set(self.fields.keys())
            for field_name in existing - allowed:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)

        if exclude is not None:
            not_allowed = set(exclude)
            for exclude_name in not_allowed:
                self.fields.pop(exclude_name)
```

Use like `serializer = UserCreateSerializer(data=data, fields=('username', 'password', 'tel'))`

that's all i know